# java reading files from zip throws exception at closeEntry

Tags: java, zip

I need to read the files inside a zip file. I am using a ZipInputStream and I iterate through the files in a while loop

```
while((ze = zipFile.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    //do stuff on file
    zipFile.closeEntry();
}
```

When in the archives are o-bytes file, I am getting the following exception at `closeEntry()`;

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried several zip files?  Maybe there is a problem with the file you are using.

Comment: yes, I tried. if I add some text inside that file, there are no issues. I have many test files, and problems are only on those that contain inside 0-byte files. Everything goes well in the debugger until the call to `closeEntry()`